# Statements to read input using Buffered Reader not getting executed

Tags: java

```
public void readList() throws IOException{

    char ch = 'N';
    String entry;
    System.out.println("__Enter entries for grocery list one__");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter Grocery Item..!!");
        entry = reader.readLine();
        this.l1.add(entry);
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue..!!(Y or N)");
        ch = (char)reader.read();
    }while(ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y');
}
```

In this object `l1` is of type `LinkedList<String>`. In the first iteration of the `do-while` loop everything runs fine , but after the first iteration :

```
entry = reader.readLine();
this.l1.add(entry);
```

are getting skipped and  `System.out.println("Do you want to continue..!!(Y or N)")` is getting executed after `System.out.println("Enter Grocery Item..!!")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ch = reader.readLine().charAt(0);`

As you are doing only a `reader.read()` it returns a integer,but the string remains in reader stream  which is automatically used in next `reader.readLine()` call ,thereby to us it looks like compiler did not stop on that line, but internally it got the entire line which it wanted

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: not by commenting , you need to click on the tick to the left of answer

Answer (score 1):

Your `read()` only reads one character and I assume after typing that character you hit `<enter>` so when you do a `readLine()` it reads the rest of this line which is empty.

I suggest you use a different format like

```
while(true) {
    System.out.println("Enter Grocery Item.. (leave the line empty when done)");
    String entry = reader.readLine();
    if (entry == null || entry.isEmpty())
        break;
    this.l1.add(entry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `read()` method a single character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 and then you hit `Enter` key so on `readLine()` its empty line. You should try it as

```
do{
    System.out.println("Enter Grocery Item..!!");
    entry = reader.readLine();
    this.l1.add(entry);
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue..!!(Y or N)");
    entry= reader.readLine();
}while(entry.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```